# Creating subset of layer intersecting with BBOX of certain features of the same layer using Virtual Layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, intersection, extents, virtual-layer

I'm trying to create a subset of one layer which includes the geometries intersecting with the bbox of certain features of the same layer.

I tried to create a Virtual Layer in QGIS with the following statement:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM layer 
WHERE st_intersects(
        (
        SELECT st_envelope(geometry)
        FROM layer
        WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
        ),
        geometry
    )
```

The statement does not raise an error. The problem is, that it only gives back the geometries intersecting with the bbox of the feature with `ID = 1` although the IDs 1, 2, 3 & 4 are included in the `WHERE` clause as list.

How would I need to change the query to include all the given IDs in the resulting subset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query doesn't work because `st_intersects()` expects a single geometry, not a table. The same query in Postgres would show `ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

To avoid returning duplicates and to avoid optimization fences, you can make use of the `where exists` clause:

```sql
SELECT * FROM myLayer a
WHERE EXISTS ( 
  SELECT 1 from myLayer sub 
  WHERE st_intersects(st_envelope(sub.geometry),a.geometry) 
   AND sub.ID IN (1,2,3,4,5));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately the Query causes QGIS to crash. The Layer I'm querying has around 4700 features. Maybe that's too much to handle.

Comment: @r.bs it shouldn't crash...  I have noticed crashes caused by virtual layer are often a consequence of a wrongly named layer (ex: keeping a reference to the alias "a" but not defining the alias) or unbalanced parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select t1.* from (
(select * from layer) t1
join
(select geometry from layer where id in (1, 2, 3, 4)) t2 --My ids were 65, 204, 212
on st_intersects(t1.geometry, st_envelope(t2.geometry))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately the Query causes QGIS to crash. The Layer I'm querying has around 4700 features. Maybe that's too much to handle.